# Python - Apply SciPy Beta Distribution to all rows of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, beta-distribution

In SciPy one can implement a beta distribution as follows:

```
x=640495496
alpha=1.5017096
beta=628.110247
A=0
B=148000000000 
p = scipy.stats.beta.cdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=A, scale=B-A)
```

Now, suppose I have a Pandas dataframe with the columns x,alpha,beta,A,B. How do I apply the beta distribution to each row, appending the result as a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I suspect that pandas apply is just looping over all rows, and the scipy.stats distributions have quite a bit of overhead in each call, I would use a vectorized version:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> df['p'] = stats.beta.cdf(df['x'], df['alpha'], df['beta'], loc=df['A'], scale=df['B']-df['A'])
>>> df
   A             B     alpha        beta          x         p
0  0  148000000000  1.501710  628.110247  640495496  0.858060
1  0  148000000000  1.501704  620.110000  640495440  0.853758
```

Answer (score 2):

Need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with function `scipy.stats.beta.cdf` and `axis=1`:

```
df['p'] = df.apply(lambda x:  scipy.stats.beta.cdf(x['x'], 
                                                   x['alpha'], 
                                                   x['beta'], 
                                                   loc=x['A'], 
                                                   scale=x['B']-x['A']), axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
import scipy.stats

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[640495496, 640495440],
                   'alpha':[1.5017096,1.5017045],
                   'beta':[628.110247, 620.110],
                   'A':[0,0],
                   'B':[148000000000,148000000000]})
print (df)
   A             B     alpha        beta          x
0  0  148000000000  1.501710  628.110247  640495496
1  0  148000000000  1.501704  620.110000  640495440

df['p'] = df.apply(lambda x:  scipy.stats.beta.cdf(x['x'], 
                                                   x['alpha'], 
                                                   x['beta'], 
                                                   loc=x['A'], 
                                                   scale=x['B']-x['A']), axis=1)
print (df)
   A             B     alpha        beta          x         p
0  0  148000000000  1.501710  628.110247  640495496  0.858060
1  0  148000000000  1.501704  620.110000  640495440  0.853758
```

Comment: I've imported scipy, but it is returning an error when I use apply: NameError: ("global name 'scipy' is not defined", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Using *only* `import scipy` will not import `scipy.stats`.  To use `scipy.stats`, you must use `import scipy.stats`.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, I am using import scipy.stats, but it still doesn't seem to be working. The answer bellow, however, does work.

Comment: Hmmm, I test it in `python 3` in spyder and it works for me. But maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @Cameron - solution of `Warren Weckesser` does not work for you? `import scipy.stats` ?

Comment: @jezrael Can you please explain What is X, A, B, are they columns of a dataframe or they are derived from raw data?? also do we have to compute the values of 'alpha' & 'beta'  for each record before applying beta function() ?